# Solidworks Feature Recognition on a fill pattern/linear pattern

Tags: vba, solidworks

I am currently creating a feature and patterning it across a flat plane to get the maximum number of features to fit on the plane. I do this frequently enough to warrant building some sort of marcro for this if possible. The issue that I run into is I still have to manually set the spacing between the parts. I want to be able to create a feature and have it determine "best" fit spacing given an area while avoiding overlaps. I have had very little luck finding any resources describing this. Any information or links to potentially helpful resources on this would be much appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Before, you start the linear pattern bit:

Select the **face2** of that **feature2**, get the outer most **loop2** of edges. You can test for that using **loop2.IsOuter**.

Now:

- if the loop has one edge: that means it's a circle and the spacing must superior to the circle's radius
- if the loop has more that one edge, that you need to calculate all the distances between the vertices and assume that the largest distance is the safest spacing.

NOTA: If one of the edges is a spline, then you need a different strategy:
You would need to convert the face into a sketch and finds the coordinates of that spline to calculate the highest distances.

**Example: The distance between the edges is lower than the distance between summit of the splines. If the linear pattern has the a vertical direction, then spacing has to be superior to the distance between the summit**.

When I say distance, I mean the distance projected on the linear pattern direction.

[image]